# Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: String '15.06.2020' was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#

```
Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: String '15.06.2020' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value)
   at Bot_NetCore.Entities.PriceList.ReadFromXML(String fileName)
   at Bot_NetCore.Bot.Main(String[] args)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Кусок кода из проекта:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bot = new Bot();

            Console.WriteLine(@"   
                Started
            ");

            ReloadSettings(); // Загрузим настройки

            MembersList.ReadFromXML(BotSettings.MemberXML);
            InviterList.ReadFromXML(BotSettings.InviterXML);
            UsersLeftList.ReadFromXML(BotSettings.UsersLeftXML);
            PriceList.ReadFromXML(BotSettings.PriceListXML);
            Vote.Read(BotSettings.VotesXML);
            Note.Read(BotSettings.NotesXML);
            Donator.Read(BotSettings.DonatorXML);
            Subscriber.Read(BotSettings.SubscriberXML);
            
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");

            bot.RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
```

Comment: *String '15.06.2020' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.* - по-моему, более чем вменяемо. Попробуйте переформатировать дату в YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как `Convert.ToDateTime` для формата использует объект `DateTimeFormatInfo` [для текущих региональных настроек](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_) из `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`:

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(String value) {
   if (value == null)
       return new DateTime(0);
   return DateTime.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

А значение `CurrentCulture` вы меняете, скорее всего, после того как отработал парсер:

```
Read xml...
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = ...
```

То логично попробовать изменить культуру до того, как читать XML.

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");

ReloadSettings(); // Загрузим настройки

...
```